# Adding or changing record in access table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I am making a rather simple inventory tracking database. And I want to retrieve the record by ID, and add or remove the specified number to the amount. If it doesn't exist I want to add it. Is it even possible to do this without binding to a table?

Comment: You can use recordsets, but why do you want to avoid binding? Working with bound forms is very simple in MS Access.

Comment: You know, that might not be that bad of an idea. The problem is that...No, wait, that should work.

Comment: Well, put it this way, I want to do it without if I can.

Comment: @Remou, I would like to avoid binding because I have a subform which is linked to its parent form with an ID, which is a required field in my table. If I try to create a new record in datasheet mode, the ID does not get populated. It doesn't make any sense to have the user input the ID, since it is already linked to its parent form. I would like to set the ID field programmatically, and an unbound form would require creating a field, keeping it invisible, and setting the value of the control. In the end, it seems more elegant to create unbound controls and insert the record programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have a candidate `ID` value.  Maybe it's contained in a numeric variable named `MyID`.  And you have another numeric value, `MyAmtChange`, which is to be added to the value in a field named `amount` in your table for the row where the `ID` field value matches `MyID`.

A complication is there may be no row in your table whose `ID` value matches `MyID`.  In that case, you need to add a row for it.

If that's correct, `INSERT` a row for `MyID` when one doesn't exist.  Then you can simply `UPDATE` the `amount` in the row which matches `MyID`.

```
Dim strInsert As String
Dim strUpdate As String
Dim db As DAO.Database

Set db = CurrentDb
If DCount("*", "YourTableNameHere", "ID = " & MyID) = 0 Then
    strInsert = "INSERT INTO YourTableNameHere (ID)" & vbCrLf & _
        "VALUES (" & MyID & ");"
    Debug.Print strInsert
    db.Execute strInsert, dbFailOnError
End If

strUpdate = "UPDATE YourTableNameHere" & vbCrLf & _
    "SET amount = Nz(amount, 0) + " & MyAmtChange & vbCrLf & _
    "WHERE ID = " & MyID & ";"
Debug.Print strUpdate
db.Execute strUpdate, dbFailOnError
Set db = Nothing
```

If this guess is reasonably close, add an error handler block to that code to deal with any issues surfaced by `dbFailOnError` ... or any other errors.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what do you want exactly, but this code show how to manipulate data with VB-Access.

```
Sub fnStudent()
    On Error GoTo insertError
    Dim studentQuery As String
    'INSERTING INTO TABLE
        studentQuery = "INSERT INTO Students values ('10','YAHYA','02/10/2012')"
        CurrentDb.Execute studentQuery, dbFailOnError
    'UPDATING
        studentQuery = "UPDATE Students Set name='YAHYA OULD ABBA' WHERE stdID='10'"
        CurrentDb.Execute studentQuery, dbFailOnError
    'LISTING VALUES
    Dim studentsRS As Recordset
    Set studentsRS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Students WHERE upper(name) like '%YAHYA%';")
    Do While Not studentsRS.EOF
        MsgBox "ID : " & studentsRS.Fields(0) & "Name : " & studentsRS.Fields(1) & "Birth Date : " & studentsRS.Fields(2)
        studentsRS.MoveNext
    Loop
    'DELETING
    studentQuery = "DELETE FROM Students WHERE stdID='10'"
    CurrentDb.Execute studentQuery, dbFailOnError
    Exit Sub 'exit if there was no error
    'UPDATE:
errorHandler:
    If Err.Number = 3022 Then
            MsgBox "Can't have duplicate key; index changes were unsuccessful",     vbMsgBoxRtlReading + vbCritical, "Error " & Err.Number
    Else : MsgBox "Error" & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbMsgBoxRtlReading + vbCritical, "Error " & Err.Number
    End If
End Sub
```

here you find a list of `vba` errors http://www.halfile.com/vb.html

Comment: What happens if I try to insert and it already exists? What about updating where it doesn't exist?

Comment: I updated the code, you can handle as many errors as you want.